# unable to set attribute dynamically for ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

If i am understand right so we need to use attribute "bsDatepicker" in input Element for ngx-bootstrap datepicker. so I want to set its attribute dynamically.

for achieving it i am using [attr.bsDatepicker]="bsDatepicker" but it set attribute in lowercase so datepicker is not working.

[image]

I also tried javascript setAttribute but got same result here is the code

```
isInputElement(elem: HTMLElement | null): elem is HTMLInputElement {
     if (!elem) {
      // null
        return false;
     }
  return (elem.tagName === 'INPUT')
}

setAttribute(id: any ){ 
const elem = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(elem);
if (this.isInputElement(elem)) {
  var att = document.createAttribute("bsDatepicker"); 
  att.value = "bsDatepicker";
  elem.setAttributeNode(att);
  console.log(elem);
}
```

}

Is there any other way to use datepicker or can i set attribute in camel-case dynamically as ngx-bootstrap datepicker required attribute "bsDatepicker".

Answer (score 0):

```
   ngClass]="
                    condition
                      ? 'disabled'
                      : 'enable'
                  "

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none !important;
  cursor: default !important;
  opacity: 0.6 !important;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?